# using orWhere in laravel gives an error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am unable to use orWhere and I don't know the reason.

My goal is to pull `amount_invoice=0 OR total_mileage=0`. My query works if I use `WHERE` clause only. When I add `orWhere`, then my query fails.

This query works:

```
$deliveries = $this->instance->delivery
        ->where('amount_invoice', 0);
        //->where('total_mileage', 0);
        //->where('amount_invoice', 0)->where('total_mileage',0);                                
        //->where('amount_invoice', 0)->orWhere('total_mileage', 0);
dd($deliveries);
```

This query works:

```
$deliveries = $this->instance->delivery
        //->where('amount_invoice', 0);
        ->where('total_mileage', 0);
        //->where('amount_invoice', 0)->where('total_mileage', 0);
        //->where('amount_invoice', 0)->orWhere('total_mileage', 0);
dd($deliveries);
```

This query works:

```
$deliveries = $this->instance->delivery
        //->where('amount_invoice', 0);
        //->where('total_mileage', 0);
        ->where('amount_invoice', 0)->where('total_mileage', 0);
        //->where('amount_invoice', 0)->orWhere('total_mileage', 0);
dd($deliveries);
```

**This query DOES NOT WORK:**

```
$deliveries = $this->instance->delivery
        //->where('amount_invoice', 0);
        //->where('total_mileage', 0);
        //->where('amount_invoice', 0)->where('total_mileage', 0);
        ->where('amount_invoice', 0)->orWhere('total_mileage', 0);
dd($deliveries);
```

I don't know what is the problem but using `orWhere` fails

Comment: You can dump the query and please explain how does it fail, an error or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what your model relationships look like, I'm guessing that

```
$this->instance->delivery
```

gives you a collection back, since that's what Laravel typically does. And `->where(...)` works to filter a collection in Laravel, but `->orWhere(...)` doesn't.

If you have

```
$this->instance->delivery()
```

instead, you get a query builder back, which you can then use to perform `->where(...)` and `->orWhere(...)` queries on. Don't forget to add an `->get()` call at the end.

Comment: To expand on what @joelhinz is saying, the `orWhere()` method is a Eloquent model method, and you are trying to use it on a Collection. Therefore, you should look into Available Collection Methods in the Laravel docs, where you may find the filter or reject methods useful.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#available-methods